# Responsive padding from left side to all the content that will display in screen

Tags: css, r, reactjs, responsive-design, react-bootstrap

Here is the code of styling component that is currently using for the component, I just want to know that how i can get the padding from left side that should be responsive

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Container, Button,Row,Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { device,device1 } from '../../Devices';

export const StyledContainer = styled(Container).attrs({
    fluid: true,
  })`
  max-width: 1538px;
  @media ${device1.mobileS} and ${device.tablet} {

  }
  @media ${device1.tablet} {


  }
`;
export const StyledRow = styled(Row).attrs({
    
})`
    height:90vh;
    background-color: #E9F8FB;
`;
export const StyledCol1 = styled(Col).attrs({
    className: 'align-self-center ps-lg-5 ps-md-3 ps-0 col-md-5 col-lg-6 col-12 text-center text-md-start',
})`
padding-left: 75px; /* Add your desired padding for smaller screens */
  
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  padding-left: 25px; /* Adjust padding for larger screens */
}
`;
export const StyledCol2 = styled(Col).attrs({
    className: 'col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-6',
})`
`;
export const StyleCol3 = styled(Col).attrs({
    className: 'col-md-4 col-xs-8 ms-5 ms-md-0',
})`

`;
export const StyledImg = styled.img.attrs({
    className: 'img-fluid p-0',
    src:'img.jpg',
    alt:'studentPicture',
    style:{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        objectFit: 'cover',
    }
})`

`;

export const StyledH1 = styled.h1.attrs({
    className: 'h1 mt-5 pt-5 pt-md-0 mt-md-0 ps-lg-5 fs-1 px-md-5 px-5 fw-bold w-100',
})`
    @media ${device.tablet} {
    /* Styles for screens up to 1080px wide */
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    }
`;
  export const StyledP = styled.p.attrs({
    className: 'p px-lg-5 pl-md-2 px-5 fs-2 mt-4 mb-5',
  })`
  
`;

export const StyledButton1 = styled(Button).attrs({
    className: 'ms-lg-4 ms-md-4 w-100 ms-5 text-center fs-3',
    variant:'primary',
})`

`;

export const StyledButton2 = styled(Button).attrs({
    className: 'w-100 btn-outline-info mt-4 ms-5 ms-md-4 mt-md-0 fs-3 mb-5 mb-md-0',
    variant:'',
})`

`;
```

type here

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
//import { Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { StyledContainer, StyledButton1,StyledButton2,StyledImg, StyledRow,StyleCol3,StyledCol1,StyledCol2,StyledH1,StyledP } from './style.js';
import Header from '../Headers'
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <StyledContainer className="p-0">
        <Header/>
      <StyledRow>
        <StyledCol1>
            <StyledH1>The Modern way to Build for the LMS</StyledH1>
            <StyledP>BRIE Empowers to build Professional, custom LMS in a completely visually canvas with no code</StyledP>
            <StyleCol3>
                <StyledButton1>Get Started</StyledButton1>
            </StyleCol3>
            <StyleCol3>
                <StyledButton2>Learn More</StyledButton2>
            </StyleCol3>
        </StyledCol1>

        <StyledCol2 > 
            <StyledImg>
            </StyledImg>
        </StyledCol2>
      </StyledRow>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I Have provided the code of the react that is displaying the content, The padding from right side should be 0, How i can set the width of the screen that should be responsive according to the screen sizes.